# Obtaining host url of sftp server from a docker container

Tags: python, django, docker, sftp

I am running django project in docker container. I have a sftp server running on another container, and wish to sftp into it from web container. Using python library paramiko from shell I can manually sftp into container by finding IP of server using docker inspect.

I wish to save sftp url in `settings.py` file and reference it later when needed.

Currently my docker-compose file has sftp image:

```
sftp:
    image: atmoz/sftp
    container_name: sftp
    volumes:
      - /host/upload:/home/
    ports:
        - "22:22"
    command: 
      - foo:pass:::upload
```

And web container has following environment variables:

```
environment:
  SFTP_USERNAME: foo
  SFTP_PASSWORD: pass
  SFTP_HOSTNAME: sftp
  SFTP_PORT: 20
```

Then in settings.py I constructed url as follows:

```
SFTP_URL = 'sftp://' + SFTP_USERNAME + ':' + SFTP_PASSWORD + '@' + SFTP_HOSTNAME + ':' + SFTP_PORT + '/'
```

this is used in `tasks.py` in a simple function for now, mostly just creating the sftp connection

```
def sftp():
    transport = paramiko.Transport((settings.SFTP_URL, int(settings.SFTP_PORT)))
    transport.connect(username = settings.SFTP_USERNAME, password = settings.SFTP_PASSWORD)

    sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)

    return sftp
```

However instead of connecting, get following error message:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/django/CustomerData/tasks.py", line 34, in sftp
    transport = paramiko.Transport((settings.SFTP_URL, int(settings.SFTP_PORT)))
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 357, in __init__
    hostname, port, socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 732, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is bugged, simply change `SFTP_URL` to `SFTP_HOSTNAME`. As far as I understand, you are confusing the names of variables

Comment: Indeed. It also turned out I didn't need to specify the port:

transport = paramiko.Transport((settings.SFTP_HOSTNAME))